# Can't resolve 'fs' in \node_modules\electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am using the electron-react boilerplate and want to use an electron `dialog` in App.tsx:

```
const { dialog } = require('@electron/remote') //also tried with import

const Hello = () => {
  const readFromFile = async () => {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({})
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => readFromFile()} >Test</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

in main.ts I placed the following line at the top

```
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()
```

In the end I always get this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\myUsername\source\repos\electronTest\node_modules\electron'
```

I also tried `nodeIntegration: true` and `contextIsolation: false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just spent a while on this and *<rant about JS community>*... eh. Maybe this will help others.

### tl;dr

You can only use electron's imports in `electron-main` side.

### longer story

Electron is split into `electron-main` and `electron-renderer`. As others suggested, you need to update `webpack`'s config with the `target` pointing at the correct *electron*.

In case you're using one of the [electron builder boilerplates](https://www.electron.build/), you might see directory `.erb` with a few webpack configs. Especially, there might be one with `target = "electron-main"` and another with `target = ["web", "electron-renderer"]`. So it feels like mission accomplished; however, according to [webpack's doc on *target*](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/), if you pass a list, then a common config is set. Since `web` doesn't include `fs`, the common part also won't include `fs`.

For the reason above, some of `electron` imports, e.g. `clipboard`, can be only used from the "electron-main" side of your application.

The work-around, e.g. using clipboard on the application side, is to use [**IPC**](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) to communicate between `main` and `renderer` sides.

Comment: I was under the impression that @electron/remote effectively provides the IPC commands to fill the gap when electron14 released.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `webpack.config.js`. Looks like you `target` is not `electron-main` or `electron-renderer`.

Comment: there are many webpack.config.ts files in the react boilerplate under .erb. There are 2 files which define target as ['web', 'electron-renderer']